# Get request on a SharePoint list

Tags: xml, vba, excel, sharepoint

I'm trying to get elements of a Sharepoint list with VBA to show and use them in an Excel sheet.

The normal get request on `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60`

```
Dim xmlObj as Object
Dim sUrl as String

sUrl = "http://<SarepointUrl>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<listTitle>')/items"
Set xmlObj = NEw MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

xmlObj.Open "GET", sUrl, False
xmlObj.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8"
xmlObj.send
Debug.Print xmlObj.responseText
```

responds with an exception:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException Access denied. You don't have permissions to perform this action.

I tried to reach the xml with an InternetExplorer object, navigating to the url of the request:

```
.../getbytitle('listTitle')/items
```

but this page on internet explorer is treated like an html page. I can take its content with `InternetExplorer.Document.body.outerText` and I would have a string with all the xml but I can't parse it in a real xml to extract datas.

```
Dim argUrl As String
Dim getUrl As String
Dim oHTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oXml As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim objIE As New InternetExplorerMedium

argUrl = "https://<SharepointUrl>"

objIE.Visible = False
objIE.Silent = False
objIE.Navigate (argUrl)
objIE.Visible = False
Application.StatusBar = argUrl & " is loading. Please wait..."
Do While objIE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

getUrl = "https://<SharepointUrl>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListTitle')/items"

objIE.Navigate (getUrl)
Application.StatusBar = getUrl & " is loading. Please wait..."
Do While objIE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

Set oHTMLDoc = objIE.Document
Set oXml = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

sXML = oHTMLDoc.body.outerText
Debug.Print sXML

'at this point it doesnt load the string as an XML because maybe this method (loadXML) needs an xml file instead of a string'
If oXml.LoadXML(sXML) Then
    Debug.Print "IF"
    Set nodeXML = xmlDoc
End If
```

Anyone has been able to solve all these problems to make a get request on a sharepoint list with vba?

Comment: sample code needed most likely

Comment: I've added some code as exemple

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
Sub GetItems()
    Const sUrl As String = "http://server/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Parent')/items"
    Dim oRequest As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Dim sResult As String
    'On Error GoTo Err_DoSomeJob

    Set oRequest = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
With oRequest
    .Open "GET", sUrl, True
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    '.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    .SetCredentials "domain\user", "pw", HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER
    .send
    .waitForResponse
    sResult = .responseText
    Debug.Print sResult
    sResult = oRequest.Status
    Debug.Print sResult
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: With this code I get status 403 Forbidden and an XML with an Exception: _"System.UnauthorizedAccesException. Access denied. You do not have permissions to perform this action or access this resource."_
But I wanted to access sharepoint list with the same credentials with which I'm logged in Microsoft Office

Comment: Have you update the "domain\user", "pw"? as the code works in my PC which host same domain with SharePoint.

Comment: Yes. And if I first open the sharepoint from InternetExplorer it can also navigate to the REST page with my datas but with an InternetExplorer object I can't do a get request